# Alternative to the use of hashbangs in the url to resolve IE9 issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, internet-explorer-9, location-provider

I'm creating a search application in angularjs with these settings:

App Config:

```
    app.config(
    [
        '$locationProvider',
        function ($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false,
                rewriteLinks: false
            });
        }
    ]
);
```

The problem is not the app itself but when im trying to access the page with IE9 im not able to access it at all. After doing som reading i found out that IE9 ignores everyting that comes after the # in an url, and redirects the user back to the host url (everything before the # in the url) And the standard fallback for html5mode is hashbang-mode. [Angular docs for $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

My question is if anyone knows if there is any way around the use of hashbangs in the url or if anyone else have this problem. If more documentation is needed, please let me know and i will provide!

EDIT: This is inside the controller:

```
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {;
        $scope.searchQuery = $location.search()['q'];
        $scope.search();
    });
```

EDIT: 
Adding `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` will not work because it will only add a "!" after the "#" in the url.

See image from angular docs:

[image: Angular docs on locationprovider]

Comment: "After doing som reading i found out that IE9 ignores everyting that comes after the # in an url, and redirects the user back to the host url".

Thats how the hash in a URL works. Angular works by taking that and parsing it into a usable url internally.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Why you're not able to access it in IE9? Did you do any troubleshooting? The fallback is correct, as we can see at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does not support history.pushState, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Therefore when you enable html5Mode like: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`
For IE9 it will fallback to the # in the URL - there is no way around this

Having said that you should still be able to use `$location.search();`
You can get the search params like this:
`var searchObject = $location.search();` 
To get a specific parameter you can do: `$location.search().paramName`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location for further information.

An alternative to the `$location` service is to inject `$routeParams`, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams
But im unsure of your use case, routeParams are only updated after a route change is completed

Comment: I enabled html5Mode but in IE9, my app gets stuck in an infinite direct loop.  How do I get the fall back #urls to work correctly?